# R error when calculating log rates of returns on portfolios (ETFs)

Tags: r, error-handling

I have tried to calculate the log rate of return for a world index (labled acw) portfolio and a country index portfolio (labled chi). The world index works but the country index gives me the error "only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts". I have combed the data and there are no zeros or negative numbers in it. I'm going insane trying to work it out. I am learning R for the first time so it is probably a very basic problem but I can't find an answer anywhere online. Here is the code,

```
> data <- read.table("C:/Documents and Settings/Emma/My Documents/data.csv",header=T,sep=",")
> data <- data.frame(data)

> td<-length(data$date)
> t<-td-1

> acwr<-250*log(data$acw[2:td]/data$acw[1:(td-1)])
> chir<-250*log(data$chi[2:td]/data$chi[1:(td-1)])
Error in data$chi[1:(td - 1)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
> traceback()
No traceback available
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: We can only guess, not being able to see your data file. The best practice for asking questions says you should try to create a minimal reproducible example - and we can't reproduce this without your data file. Also, what is the point of t<-td-1 when you don't use 't' again?

Comment: Give us the data file. Or try it with the first ten lines of the data file and give us those ten lines. Or at least give us summary(data). I can't duplicate this error.

Comment: My preferred method for calculating log returns is `diff(log(data$acw))` (although I'd do it via `TTR::ROC`)

Answer (score 2):

This is all based on guesswork of course...

But I think....

Your data has no `date` column. Your fundamental failure is not checking this.

Hence `td` is zero. Your second failure is not checking this.

You then try and subscript `data$acw[1:(td-1)]`. This works, you say, in that it doesn't return an error. But you haven't checked this. I guess it returns NULL because your data HAS NO `acw` column. So `data$acw` is NULL, and R doesn't care how you try and subset NULL. You get back NULL. Your third failure is not checking this.

You then try and subscript `data$chi[1:(td-1)]`. This fails, because `data$chi` exists, and:

```
> 1:(td-1)
[1]  1  0 -1
```

so your subscript has +1 and -1 in it.

And in R subscripts, this is saying to get the element 1 and not element 1 (the zero is irrelevant). So it fails.

All this would have been obvious if you'd done `summary(data)` or shown us the data file. Currently it is just speculation until you show us these things, and it would have saved me twenty minutes.

Try and break down your R into elements and check they are all what you expect them to be. As an interpreted language, R makes this easy for you.

What you should really do of course, is not check the length of an element to get the number of rows of a dataframe as you try with `data$date`. There's an `nrow` function for that.